# Override Go JSON tag values at runtime

Tags: json, go

I have the following struct in in my Web Application using "encoding/json"

```
type CourseAssignment struct {
    Semester int `json:"semester"  xml:"semester"`
    Lecture Lecture `json:"-"  xml:"-"`
    Cos Cos `json:"-"  xml:"-"`
    Links map[string][]Link `json:"links,omitempty" xml:"links,omitempty"`
}
```

Lecture and Cos are complex structs themselves that i dont want to be included in my serialized json which i indicate by setting json:"-"

This works perfectly.

How do I override that behavior on demand during runtime, without writing my own Serialization code?

My Own Solution:

```
func (r *CourseAssignment) Expand(depth int) CourseAssignment {

    if depth <= 0 {
        return *r
    }

    tmp := *r
    tmp.LectureEx = tmp.Lecture
    tmp.CosEx = tmp.Cos
    tmp.Links = nil 
    return tmp
}

type CourseAssignment struct {
    Semester int `json:"semester"  xml:"semester"`
    Lecture *Lecture `json:"-"  xml:"-"`
    Cos *Cos `json:"-"  xml:"-"`
    Links map[string][]Link `json:"links,omitempty" xml:"links,omitempty"`
    LectureEx  *Lecture   `json:"lecture,omitempty"  xml:"lecture,omitempty"`
    CosEx *Cos `json:"course_of_study,omitempty" xml:"course_of_study,omitempty"`   
}
```

When I want to include the fields, I create a Copy of the Object using `Expand` that fills fields that contain the same references but show up in the serialization.

Answer (score 4):

You can **read/get** struct tag values using `StructTag` from `reflect` package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type CourseAssignment struct {
    Semester int `json:"semester"  xml:"semester"`
}

func main() {
    ca := CourseAssignment{}
    st := reflect.TypeOf(ca)
    field := st.Field(0)
    fmt.Println(field.Tag.Get("json"))
}
```

There is no method to **change** a struct tag field in the standard library.

However, there are open-source libraries that do exactly that, like [Retag](https://github.com/sevlyar/retag).

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in similar cases is to set these kinds of fields to `omitempty`, and then empty them before serializing in the cases where I don't want them included in JSON:

```
type CourseAssignment struct {
    Semester int `json:"semester"  xml:"semester"`
    Lecture *Lecture `json:"lecture,omitempty"  xml:"-"`
    Cos *Cos `json:"cos,omitempty"  xml:"-"`
    Links map[string][]Link `json:"links,omitempty" xml:"links,omitempty"`
}

// Want to serialize without including Lecture/Cos:
aCourseAssignment.Lecture = nil
aCourseAssignment.Cos = nil
thing,err := json.Marshal(aCourseAssignment)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i ended up doing something similar:

Comment: This isn't useful when we want to avoid having the field names in the result.

Comment: @pinkpanther how do you figure? The point of `omitempty` is the field is omitted if the field is empty.

Comment: You should try to nest the core model in another wrapper model like described in this blog post: https://attilaolah.eu/2014/09/10/json-and-struct-composition-in-go/ instead of this hack